# solr autocomplete with scope is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I'm dig into **solr** configuration stuff and try to figure out how implement autocomplete feature.

Some details mentioned here http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester/

But I don't want use same dictionary for all site - it is not useful when you have some private data. I mean several companies use search and I want make autocompleate based only on company data. Is it possible to limit autocompleate results scope them with some syntax.

I'm working with **Rails 3** and **sunspot gem** and **solr 3.6**

**Update:**

I found gem which updated for **rails 3** and necessary configuration documented
here is it https://github.com/xponrails/sunspot_autocomplete

**Both answers help me to do thats**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to filter auto-suggestions made through the `Suggester`.
You might want to have a look at [this blog](http://www.searchworkings.org/blog/-/blogs/different-ways-to-make-auto-suggestions-with-solr) I wrote for other options you have. You should consider using either the facet prefix or the NGrams solution described in the article. The Ngrams solution is more flexible and a little more performant I guess but will cause the growth of your index size, while the facet prefix method is ready to go but probably slower. Just give them a try to see which one you prefer.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my answer with some more details. Let me know if you have any further question!

Answer (score 1):

I am using an EdgeNgram field and make the autocomplete queries against it.

Something like this in your schema.xml:

```
<field name="title_auto" type="edge_ngram" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

Querying "test" looks like

```
Jul 20, 2012 12:28:58 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/select/ params={spellcheck=true&sort=date+desc fl=*+score&start=0&q=title_auto:(test)&spellcheck.count=1&spellcheck.collate=true&wt=json hits=0 status=0 QTime=2
```

Even though I am using a third party app to send out the queries to Solr (Django-Haystack), the above query should be similar to what you are looking for.