# Trying to implement scoped autosuggestions with solr

Tags: search, solr, autocomplete, solrj, autosuggest

I am trying to implement scoped autosuggestions like in ecommerce websites like amazon etc.

eg.
if i type **Lego** , the suggestions should come like

- **Lego**las in Names
- **Lego** in Toys

where **Names** and **Toys** are solr field names.

closest aid i got is from this discussion:
[solr autocomplete with scope is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575727/solr-autocomplete-with-scope-is-it-possible)

Which informed me that it isn't possible with the [suggester](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester) which I am currently using.

Until now, using the suggester I am able to achieve autosuggestions from a single solr field. [the autosuggest field , following guidelines in the suggester documentation]

Any ideas/links to help me with ?

**Update**

I tried to achieve autosuggestions using facets. My query looks something like:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/select?q=*%3A*&rows=0&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=field1&facet.field=field2&facet.prefix=i
```

This gives me all the facet results starting with letter 'i' and term faceted to field1 and field2.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074681/predictive-autosuggest-logic) gave me the idea.

Any comments?

Comment: You can use a copyField to copy Names and Toys into one field, and then use an edge ngram to create wildcard tokens. Then you can use that as your field for your suggester, or you may have better luck using it as a field with select. You should try some experimentation.

Comment: @TMBTupdated my answer with what I have experimented.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are storing the `Names` or `Toys` data as in a field, let call it `category`.

You can configure the `payloadField` parameter in the `searchComponent` definition and pass the `category` data into it. Later in the application when you receive the suggestion results from solr, show first suggestion from each `category` or which ever strategy suits better for your use case.

You can find the more information in [Solr Suggester](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester).

Comment: can you show some snippet for better understanding? even some documentation link on how can i use payloadField?

Comment: @SumeetSharma `<str name="payloadField">category</str>` add this into the `searchComponent` tag.

Answer (score 0):

1. Suggester component seems useful but in payload field, one can only return a single field which may not satisfy many of the use cases.
2. By Facet prefixing, you cannot get suggestions from a word in the middle. So "Lego" will give suggestion of a product whose value in name field is "Legolas Sample" but not from "Sample Legolas".
3. The third way is to implement autosuggest is by using a index analyzer that has a layer of `EdgeNGramFilterFactory` and then searching on the required prefix.

So, the solr schema will look like

```
<field name="names" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="toys" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="names_ngram" type="text_suggest_ngram" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="toys_ngram" type="text_suggest_ngram" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

and the field type would have a definition of

```
<fieldType name="text_suggest_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="10" minGramSize="2"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

and these `_ngram` fields would be a copyfield:

```
<copyField source="names" dest="names_ngram"/>
<copyField source="toys" dest="toys_ngram"/>
```

So , once you have reindexed your data, if you query for "Lego" it will give results from both "Sample Legolas" and "Legolas Sample". However, if you have to categorize these results according to n fields they matched, that would be n different queries which is usually not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple suggester components.
Add one for each field.

E.g. :

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">namesSuggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">BlendedInfixLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">Names</str>
    <str name="weightField">Popularity</str>
    <str name="indexPath">namesSuggesterIndexDir</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">suggester</str>
  </lst>
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">toysSuggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">BlendedInfixLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">Toys</str>
    <str name="weightField">Popularity</str>
    <str name="indexPath">toysSuggesterIndexDir</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">suggester</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

Comment: Good work around but not a solution that will be helpful in the long run.. what if i want to move to dynamic fields in future ? even for adding a new field i would need to update the config file..  
anyway i implemented it using facets, more details on the same in the update on my question... thanks anyway .. :)