# Solr Autocomplete

Tags: solr, autocomplete

Consider a Solr Document with the following fields id,title,city,locality,category,subcategory(multivalued) and tags(multivalued).

Here the autocomplete is on title,category,subcategory,tags and locality fields.In order to achieve this I use an autocomplete field and copy all
the necessary fields namely title,category etc... to it and things works fine.Used highlighting(due to presence of multivalued fields) for achieving it.

But,I am facing difficulty in identifying to which field the autocomplete term belongs to?

For example say I search for cricket,it could be either a part of title or tags.Is there a way wherein I can find this out using the above method?

Comment: This question and its answers (though still none accepted) may shed some light on the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33501053/trying-to-implement-scoped-autosuggestions-with-solr

Answer (score 0):

By default Solr search for all the fields, you can use faceted search if you want to search a specific field. For example,

```
      fq=title:"Cricket"
```

This will search in the field which you specified.

Comment: But my autocomplete field is a composition of other fields so I wouldn't be able to know to which field the term belongs to?Here in your example you are explicitly searching in the title field,but it could be in any other field?